# change usb drive mode: portable/fixed (windows7)

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I have this usb hard drive which have always been mounted as removable on windows 7.
Suddenly it started to be mounted as fixed and windows started creatin annoying "system volume information" and "$recycke.bin" folders on it.
I willing to put it back into removable media mode.
I did some search but I didn't find any immediate solution.
I appreciate any information.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487419 , from that I get. the classID defines it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff546289(v=VS.85).aspx. If a Vendor put in thier OWN driver it would not be going through the normal MS driver. The low possibility that a legasy boot BIOS support way back at the beginning could even allow a removable to be fully "bootable". (I dont know if that could change it once the OS drivers it).  First thing I would check for, is the driver it uses, via any software installed to repurpose it.

Comment: i read it before. I can't find a solution there though.

Comment: Yes probably not even close to solution. but because we cannot see what your doing, could you indicate if the drive uses USBSTOR driver?  What does the ID for the device show?  Are any Bios options set to allow it to boot? How is its "status" listed in DIsk Manager, does it have System, Page-File, or Boot Designation?